# Longitudinal data analysis

Tags: r, panel-data, mixed-model

I have a question regarding longitudinal study analysis. I tried to search similar questions like mine but didn't really find it.

So here is the brief description of data and my question:

I have a data set with 106 subjects. For each subj, I have two repeated measures (say M1, M2) collected at four different times (say T1, T2, T3, T4 <- Time factor). There are also two factors (Gender and Group).

I would like to build a mixed model in r trying to know the association between M2 and "Group" X "Gender" X "Time" given M1. Here M1 is like an influence variable that we believe that it could affect our analysis accuracy if we don't include it in the model. However, M1 is another repeated measures like M2 that was observed at four different times from the same subj.

Now, I am not sure how to correctly write a model that is exactly what I want. 
I tried something like below : (nlme package in r)

```
lme <- lme(M2 ~ group * gender * (M1/time), 
data, random= ~ 1|subj, 
corr=corSymm(form = ~ 1 | subj), 
weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | time))
```

I actually have a feeling that I probably shouldn't use M1 nested within Time but it might be even weird if I use M1 as a main effect directly.

Is there anyone that could provide some other idea? I would very appreciate! Thanks!

PS. 
For your information, please see below for the first 6 subjects of my data:

```
Subj    M2  M1  Time    Gender  Group
1   0.595   0.0832  1   0   0
1   0.372   -0.2154 2   0   0
1   0.234   -0.1556 3   0   0
1   0.08    -0.2034 4   0   0
2   0.345   -0.1237 1   0   0
2   2.6468  -0.4454 2   0   0
2   0.134   -0.4282 3   0   0
2   0.09    -0.5797 4   0   0
3   0.321   -0.4213 1   0   0
3   0.43    -0.4138 2   0   0
3   0.104   -0.4041 3   0   0
3   0.132   -0.177  4   0   0
4   0.262   -0.4737 1   0   0
4   1.4661  -0.0675 2   0   0
4   0.115   -0.4599 3   0   0
4   0.115   -0.4882 4   0   0
5   0.07    0.2125  1   0   1
5   0.497   0.1559  2   0   1
5   0.085   0.5457  3   0   1
5   0.07    0.7267  4   0   1
6   0.293   -0.5728 1   1   0
6   0.892   -0.0837 2   1   0
6   0.373   -0.2663 3   1   0
6   0.145   0.7611  4   1   0
```